# Passing textbox instance to method group

Tags: c#, overloading

I made a method to loop and clear all *textbox* controls in my form.

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(tb => tb.Clear());
```

This works just fine, but I figured that since the first argument passed to any instance method is always a reference to the instance that I should be able to write it like this

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(TextBox.Clear);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't actually work, and I don't quite understand why..

Answer (score 4):

It would work if `TextBox.Clear` was a static method with a `TextBox` parameter; but instead, it's an instance method with no parameters, so the compiler can't automatically transform it to an `Action<TextBox>`.

Note that the CLR *does* support open-instance delegates (you can create one with the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` method), but the C# language doesn't support it.

Here's how to create an open-instance delegate that will invoke `TextBox.Clear` on its argument:

```
var action = (Action<TextBox>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<TextBox>),
    null,
    typeof(TextBox).GetMethod("Clear"));
```

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, it *could*.  It *doesn't*.

Comment: Isn't there any easy way to reference the instance methods? Aside from the way I'm doing it.. It just "seems" unclean, we are referencing the instances already in the `ForEach()` but we can't just write `ForEach(Clear)`..

Comment: @OverlyExcessive You could create a static method that called the instance method.  That is of course what the anonymous method is doing for you; you could simply give it a name if you wanted.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thank you for providing a detailed example on how we could do it by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`. Although in this case I think it would be *overkill* to create a new delegate and also to use *reflection* for this purpose. Nevertheless, I've learnt something new.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive, yes, in this case it would probably be overly excessive ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `this` parameter is implicit, not explicit.  `Foreach` is expecting a method with an *explicit* parameter, not an implicit one.

As for why the C# language team didn't implement this feature, you'll have to ask them.  They of course *could* have designed the language to support this, if they wanted to.  There's no real point in us speculating as to why they didn't.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive You're expecting a feature to have been implemented that the C# language team didn't implement.  It happens all the time; people expect every language to just have features that it doesn't have.  It's just something that you're going to have to live with as a programmer.